# Flutter display pop-up once based on value

Tags: flutter, popup, sharedpreferences

I am trying to display a pop-up dialog like (+20) based on the value coming from server. I have a variable name ageRestriction which is getting the value from server. And I want to display pop-up based on the value of this variable. (Eg: If ageRestriction has the value of "18" the pop-up will be displayed only once then later on if the value will change to "20" the pop-up will be displayed once again, so these values will be stored somewhere and the pop-up will not be displayed if the same value comes again)

I have tried to do it with shared preferences unfortunately it did not work:

```
// initializing shared pref
@override
  void initState() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  widget.ageRestriction = await prefs.getString("ageRestriction");
  await prefs.setString("ageRestriction", widget.ageRestriction);
  }


// displaying pop-up dialog
      widget.ageRestriction.toString() == widget.ageRestriction ? null :
                            AwesomeDialog(
                              popContext: false,
                              context: context,
                              dialogType: DialogType.WARNING,
                              animType: AnimType.TOPSLIDE,
                              title: "${widget.ageRestriction} Warning",
                              desc: "We only sell this product to persons who are ${widget.ageRestriction} years old. Age will be verified upon delivery.",
                              btnOkText: "Continue",
                              btnOkOnPress: () async{
                                widget.onPressed();
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              btnCancelOnPress: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              btnCancelText: S.current.cancel,
                              btnOkColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              btnCancelColor: Color(0xFF084457).withOpacity(0.9),
                            ).show();
                            ageRestrict();
                          }
```

Comment: Why are you overwriting widget.ageRestriction? Always be true, widget.ageRestriction.toString() == widget.ageRestriction and where are you calling display popup dialog?

Comment: Basically, you want to show alert dialog based on a condition?

Comment: yes exactly, it should appear only once

Comment: @Ninja Yes here is the problem I have issue with logic,  AwesomeDialog displays the pop-up dialog, Any idea to make this thing based on condition above ?

Answer (score 0):

Store `widget.ageRestriction` in a variable in the state of the widget and then check in `didUpdateWidget` whether the value changed and if it did show the popup

Answer (score 0):

Simple Demo App to show age restriction :

```dart
Future<String> getAgeRestrictionFromServer() async {
  // write your own logic
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  return "22";
}

enum RequestState { LOADING, SUCCESS, ERROR }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>{
  // request status
  RequestState requestState = RequestState.LOADING;
  // disable multiple clickes
  bool retryButtonEnabled = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      getData();
    });
  }

  showAgeRestrictionDialog(String age) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Age policy changed!'),
        content: Text('New Age: $age'),
      ),
    );
  }

  void changeRequestState(RequestState newRequestState) {
    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {
        requestState = newRequestState;
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    changeRequestState(RequestState.LOADING);
    try {
      // get age from server
      var newAgeRestriction = await getAgeRestrictionFromServer();

      // get age stored locally
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
          await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var previousAgeRestriction =
          sharedPreferences.getString('ageRestriction');
      print('$previousAgeRestriction, $newAgeRestriction');
      int.parse(newAgeRestriction);
      if (mounted) {
        // compare previous and new age
        if (previousAgeRestriction != newAgeRestriction) {
          // save new age
          await sharedPreferences.setString(
              'ageRestriction', newAgeRestriction);
          // show dialog because age changed
          showAgeRestrictionDialog(newAgeRestriction);
        }
      }
      retryButtonEnabled = true;
      changeRequestState(RequestState.SUCCESS);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      retryButtonEnabled = true;
      changeRequestState(RequestState.ERROR);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var child;
    if (requestState == RequestState.LOADING) {
      child = Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (requestState == RequestState.SUCCESS) {
      child = Center(
        child: Text('Got data from server!'),
      );
    } else {
      child = Center(
        child: FlatButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            onPressed: retryButtonEnabled
                ? () {
                    setState(() {
                      retryButtonEnabled = false;
                    });
                    getData();
                  }
                : null,
            child: Text('Retry')),
      );
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Demo App'),
      ),
      body: child,
    );
  }
}
```

More info about state management [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)